# Is the linear map on basis of $V$ a basis of $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $v_1,...v_n$ is a base of $V$, is $T(v_1),...T(v_n)$ a base of $W$?

If yes, how to prove it?

The reason I have this question is when I am reading the definition of *matrix of a linear map*, it said,

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $v_1,...v_n$ is a base of $V$, and $w_1,...,w_m$ is a base of $W$. The matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases is the m by n matrix $M(T)$ whose entries $A_{jk}$ are defined by $$Tv_k = A_{1,k}w_1 + ...+ A_{m,k}w_m$$

Based on the definition, for every vector in the base of $V$, after we transformed it by $T$, we will get a vector that can be expressed by $w_1,...,w_m$. And the definition said $w_1,...,w_m$ is a basis. So, I am wondering, if $T(v_1),...T(v_n)$ a base of $W$?

Comment: Suppose $T(\vec v)=\vec 0$ $\;\forall \vec v\in V$.

Comment: The basis of $W$ is $w_1,\dots,w_m$.  All is said about  $Tv_1, \dots,Tv_n$ is that they have an expression in function of $w_1,  \dots,w_m$.

Comment: In fact, if $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then $T(v_1), \ldots, T(v_n)$ is a basis of $W$ if and only if $T$ is an isomorphism.  (And, they're linearly independent if and only if $T$ is injective.  They span $W$ if and only if $T$ is surjective.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
This is not true.Consider $A:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ defined by $A(v)= 0$ (by zero i think zero vector).